# Extractig public key value via PKCS#11

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop, softhsm

I am using Pkcs11 library to retreive key from device:
[image: public_keys]

I am able to retreive ObjectHandle of public key. I try to extract public key value:

```
var publicKeyHandle = GetPublicKeyByLabel(Session, "KEY1_QAL_PUB");
var objectAttribute = Session.GetAttributeValue(publicKeyHandle, new List<CKA> { CKA.CKA_VALUE }).Single();
var keyVal =  objectAttribute.GetValueAsByteArray();
```

Unfortunately, `objectAttribute` has `CannotBeRead` set to `true` and value cannot be read. **Even when I am  logged as user or SO.**

I understand the case, when the key is private - due to security reasons I cannot get value outside HSM device. But why I cannot extract public key value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CKA_VALUE` is not a valid attribute for RSA public key objects. If you want to extract RSA public key value then you need to read `CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT` and `CKA_MODULUS` attributes. See [PKCS#11 v2.20](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20) for more details.

Comment: Ahh right. With exponent and modulus values it is quite easy to create public key.